# How to know an Apache web server mod_cgi module is enabled?

Tags: penetration-test, webserver, apache

I am currently working on penetration test of a web site that uses an Apache HTTP server. To test a vulnerability which is related to mod_cgi module, I need to know whether this web site uses mod_cgi module of Apache or not? How can I determine this?

Answer (score 1):

The first place to look is the server header. Depending on the server configuration it may report all enabled modules. Alternately you can use a specially formulated request which will provide a less reliable detection. The AddHandler directive allows a script to answer with a non 501 response to incorrect HTTP verbs. I'm using this technique in my Apache profiling script (aprof) from my lbmap project: https://github.com/wireghoul/lbmap

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I want to use lbmap aprof tool to detect which Apache modules are used. I downloaded this project from github, but how can I use this tool?

Comment: You run it the same way you run any perl file. Also, was there a reason you had to detect mod_cgi first as opposed to simply running the exploit?